# How to floor if less than a penny, else do not

Tags: javascript, math, decimal, floor

What is the best way to check if the value is a penny or under. If under return 0 else a Math.floored value.

The code below currently will return a value of $0.01 if the price_usd is something like `00.0031`. What is should return is `0`.

However if the value is `00.56` it should return .56 cents which is does now.

```
const rounder = (balance, price_usd) => round(multiply(balance, price_usd));

constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
        asset: props.asset,
        balance: props.balance,
        value: rounder(props.balance, props.price_usd)
    };
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
}

// value: rounder(props.balance, Math.floor(props.price_usd))
```

Comment: Multiply by 100 and check if the integer component is less than 1?

Comment: How much is a penny?

Comment: result = v<penny:0:Math.floor(v);

Comment: It would probably be better to do all the calculations in cents and only convert to dollars and cents for display. That way you can avoid the problems that can come along with floating-point arithmetic: [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it using this trick.

```js
var num1 = 0.56,
    num2 = 0.0031;

console.log(Math.floor(num1 * 100) / 100); // 0.56
console.log(Math.floor(num2 * 100) / 100); // 0.00
```

Comment: That actually, didn't work for me. The .0031 rounded up to `0.1`

Comment: It should return `0` run this in your browser `console` to check it `console.log(Math.floor(0.0031  * 100) / 100); // 0`

Comment: Code uploaded here: https://github.com/CoinHover/coinhover.io/commit/b99720cb5f9f8556e92435c314b7d12fe43e45bf

Comment: Ah thanks, tried it again and this is simpler than parse

Answer (score 1):

Solution

```
parseFloat(Number(price_usd).toFixed(2))
```